# Cannot add foreign key constraint when forward engineering

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've looked through many posts with the same issue as mine, except I still can't figure out what is causing this error to occur.
I've checked data types, and they are all consistent. I've checked if something was unsigned, that's not the case. I went through all columns, and their collation is set to Table default, and each table is set to utf8. I even just completely removed the foreign key constraints and attempted to forward engineer again, and it still happens.

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Melendez`.`Books` (
      `ISBN` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Author` INT NOT NULL,
      `Publisher` INT NOT NULL,
      `YearPublished` INT NULL,
      `Genre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Quantity` INT NULL,
      `NumAvailable` INT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ISBN`),
      INDEX `AuthorFK_idx` (`Author` ASC),
      INDEX `PublisherFK_idx` (`Publisher` ASC),
      INDEX `GenreFK_idx` (`Genre` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `AuthorFK`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Author`)
        REFERENCES `Melendez`.`Authors` (`AuthorID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `PublisherFK`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Publisher`)
        REFERENCES `Melendez`.`Publishers` (`PublisherID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `GenreFK`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Genre`)
        REFERENCES `Melendez`.`Genres` (`Genre`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

This is the statement that's throwing the error.
Here are the create table statements for the 3 tables referenced:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Melendez`.`Authors` (
`AuthorID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`MI` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`AuthorID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Melendez`.`Publishers` (
`PublisherID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`PublisherName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`PublisherID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Melendez`.`Genres` (
`Genre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Section` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Genre`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Is there something else I can look for? I feel like I looked everywhere. Or maybe it's something obvious I looked right over.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue using your code. Please add the full error message,

Comment: I've since solved the issue, it seemed like a bug. I ended up copying and pasting the statements one by one and executing them manually, and everything was successfully created. Something in the model must have been corrupted. I then reverse engineered the database to generate a model which gave me no issues.